# Combining sample() and group_by() from tidyvese

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, sample

Below, I'm trying to randomly select the rows of a `group` value in each `study` in my `data`, how?

Well, we first `group_by(study)`, then decide to pick one of the `group`'s rows in each `study` based on:

```
group_row <- sapply(1:length(unique(data$study)), 
                     function(i)sample(0:2, 1, replace = TRUE))
```

For each `study` in `group_by(study)`:

if `group_row` was `1`, select `group == 1` rows of that `study`.

if `group_row` was `2`, select `group == 2` rows of that `study`.

if `group_row` was `0`, select  ALL rows of that `study`.

***I have tried the following without success?***

```
library(tidyverse)

(data <- expand_grid(study=1:3,group=1:2,outcome=c("A","B"), time=0:1) %>%
    as.data.frame())


lapply(1:2, function(i){
data %>% dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
    filter(group == if(group_row[i] ==0) unique(data$group) else group_row[i]) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% arrange(study,group,outcome,time)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function to select a row for each `study` and apply the function by group.

```
library(dplyr)

return_rows <- function(x) {
  n <- sample(0:2, 1)
  #If n = 0 select all rows else 
  #select row for corresponding group
  if(n == 0) TRUE else x == n
}


data %>%
  group_by(study) %>%
  filter(return_rows(group)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Your shortcut issue seems to be a bug in RStudio (https://community.rstudio.com/t/ctrl-shift-m-pipe-operator-shortcut-is-suddenly-stop-working-since-this-morning/118362) - I would guess the devs are working on it, but it's worth posting your information on that page too

Comment: Not when you are sampling only 1 number.